# How to show 2d grid plane in 3d ViewPort in WPF

Tags: wpf

As a starting point for a 3d workspace (Where I will play around with 3d modelling), how could I show a 2d grid to represent the horizonal plane as show below in WPF?

[image: 2d grid plane in 3d viewport]

-- Lee

Comment: I'm currently checking out the Helix toolkit http://helix-toolkit.github.io/demos/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Helix Toolkit, this should work:

```
<h:GridLinesVisual3D Width="180" Length="120" Thickness="0.1" MinorDistance="5" MajorDistance="10" Fill="Black"/>
```